# Erlang Mnesia Select result not same as read, foldl

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a situation with 3 use cases for returning data from an mnesia table
1. return all values of a table so I use a foldl, 
2. return 1 row so I use read 
3. return a variable number of records based on criteria so I use select.

I would like to use the same code to manage the results, but the select returns a different data structure. I am hoping someone can help me restructure my select to return the same as the others.

below is sample code of the issue and the results.  The issue is the select does not return the record name for the table as does read and foldl.

```
-module(testselect2).

-export([runtest/0]).

-record(record_a, {b, c, d}).
-record(record_b, {record_a, e}).
-record(record_c, {record_b, f, intval}).
runtest() ->
mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
mnesia:start(),
mnesia:create_table(record_c, [{attributes, record_info(fields, record_c)}]),

A1 = #record_a{b = "R1", c = "T1", d = "C1"},
B1 = #record_b{record_a = A1, e = "E1"},
C1 = #record_c{record_b = B1, f = "F1", intval = 100},    

A2 = #record_a{b = "R2", c = "T2", d = "C2"},
B2 = #record_b{record_a = A2, e = "E2"},
C2 = #record_c{record_b = B2, f = "F2", intval = 200},    

A3 = #record_a{b = "R3", c = "T3", d = "C3"},
B3 = #record_b{record_a = A3, e = "E3"},
C3 = #record_c{record_b = B3, f = "F3", intval = 300},    

{atomic, Rw} = mnesia:transaction(
              fun () ->
                mnesia:write(C1),
                mnesia:write(C2),
                mnesia:write(C3)                    
              end),


io:fwrite("Result write = ~w~n", [Rw]),   

{atomic, Rr} = mnesia:transaction(
              fun () ->
                      mnesia:read({record_c, B1})

              end),
io:fwrite("Result read = ~w~n", [Rr]),   

{atomic, Rf} =
           mnesia:transaction(fun () ->
                                      mnesia:foldl(fun (Rec, Acc) -> [Rec | Acc] end,
                                                   [],
                                                   record_c)
                              end),
io:fwrite("Result foldl = ~w~n", [Rf]),                                         

MatchHead = #record_c{record_b='$1', f='$2',  intval='$3'},
Guard = {'>', '$3', 100},
Result = {{'$1', '$2', '$3'}}, 
{atomic, Rs} = mnesia:transaction(
              fun () ->  
                  mnesia:select(record_c, [{MatchHead, [Guard], [Result]}])
              end),
io:fwrite("Result select = ~w~n", [Rs]).
```

=====
RESULTS

44> testselect2:runtest().

Result write = ok

Result read = [{record_c,{record_b,{record_a,[82,49],[84,49],[67,49]},[69,49]},[70,49],100}]

Result foldl = [{record_c,{record_b,{record_a,[82,49],[84,49],[67,49]},[69,49]},[70,49],100},{record_c,{record_b,{record_a,[82,51],[84,51],[67,51]},[69,51]},[70,51],300},{record_c,{record_b,{record_a,[82,50],[84,50],[67,50]},[69,50]},[70,50],200}]

Result select = [{{record_b,{record_a,[82,51],[84,51],[67,51]},[69,51]},[70,51],300},{{record_b,{record_a,[82,50],[84,50],[67,50]},[69,50]},[70,50],200}]

## ok

As you can see above read and foldl records start with {record_c,{... where select is missing the record_c and just has {{...

I have been unable to find a way to get select to return the same structure so my processing code can work for all 3 use cases. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no mnesia expert, but I know when you use an ETS match expression, you determine what the result looks like. You use `Result = {{'$1', '$2', '$3'}}` to create your result terms, which makes them come out as three-tuples in a one-tuple, as we see in your output. Per [`ets:select/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select-1), you want to use the special variable `'$_'` to return the whole matched object, so this should work in place of your `Result = ...` line:

```
Result = '$_',
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I really do appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @Gregg np. If an answer on SO solves your problem, you'll want to mark it "accepted" and/or upvote it to help future users identify good answers.